# Name for Travel.SE chat room

Tags: discussion, chat

Not a particularly serious discussion but I think it should be fun. Does anyone have name suggestions for [Travel.SE's chat room](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/591/travel)? 'Travel' sounds meh. For example, Writers.SE call theirs [The Overlook Hotel](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/168/the-overlook-hotel), Superuser call theirs [Root Access](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/118).

Comment: I'm thinking something like what the airlines call their special lounges for frequent fliers. But I don't know them off the top of my head...

Comment: Too bad some good ones are already taken such as "Footprints", "Let's Go", and the very poetic "Lonely Planet".

Comment: Others such as "On The Road" and "Off the Beaten Track" might be regarded as already taken...?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Here's one we should all be familiar with from staring at helpful tourist maps anywhere in the world:

**You Are Here**

Comment: this is looking like the popular one at present...

Comment: I was thinking so too but still only by one vote. Should we give ourselves a deadline and if there is a clear winner at that point go with it? Say one week?

Comment: Perhaps a new thread with the top 10 candidates, and people can comment with their first and second preferences.  Once we have more than say 15 people comment, we should have a winner?

Comment: Yes I was thinking about that too. Maybe we can ask people to vote up the question, or add a comment, as a way of tracking how many people bothered to vote. It's a shame we can't put a bounty on meta questions (-: I say just go for it on your own or among your fellow diamonds.

Answer (score 5):

Since there's still no clear winner I thought up some more:

**Bon Voyage**

Answer (score 4):

Or if you didn't like the others how about:

**In Transit**

Comment: This one sounds the best of all...

Answer (score 4):

Since there's still no clear winner I thought up some more:

**Wanderlust**

Answer (score 4):

Another one to consider:

***Walkabout***

Answer (score 4):

How about:

**The Transit Lounge**

Answer (score 3):

Or how about:

**Departure Lounge**

Answer (score 3):

One with an older train/ship feel, but possibly a bit cliched:

**All Aboard!**

Answer (score 3):

Since there's still no clear winner I thought up some more:

**Itchy Feet**

Answer (score 2):

And a Simpson's inspired one:

**Are We There Yet?**

Answer (score 2):

Suddenly had this idea of remote places and the one most often cited as being waaay out there - **Timbuktu** !

Comment: Or a variant like **Timbuktu to Kalamazoo**, from perhaps Dr Seuss?

Comment: I thought of this theme too but not this example. Mine all sounded too Australia specific: **Beyong the Black Stump**, **The Back of Beyond**, **Woop Woop** so I went with **Middle of Nowhere** instead. Should I bring in any of those others though?

Answer (score 1):

**The Travellers' Lounge**

**Pit Stop**

**Watering Hole**

Answer (score 1):

**The Tourist Trap**!

<sup>Seemed to emerge in my head while thinking about this in my sleep (-:</sup>

Comment: I loved the irony but I suppose some take the negative implication too seriously...

Answer (score 1):

There doesn't seem to be any standard or obvious "travel + meeting" metaphor but there are places where we at least crowd around...

**Baggage Carousel**

Answer (score 1):

How about:

**The Middle of Nowhere**

Answer (score 1):

OK one more answer from me:

**Small World**

<sup>or some variant thereof</sup>

Answer (score 1):

Here's one more which is kind of "listy" in some slight way like a logged chatroom and also travelish:

**The Itinerary**

Answer (score 1):

One that emerged after a random, random discussion in the chat room:

**There and Back**

Answer (score 1):

Another one that I thought of after thinking about where I get most of my information while travelling:

The Common Room

Comment: I kept thinking of this one too but always thought too many people wouldn't grok it.

Answer (score 0):

More from me all variations on a theme:

**The Way**

**The Route**

**En Route**

**On the Way**

Answer (score -1):

I tried to think of some "room" related ones that are also travel-related:

**The Map Room**

**The Chart Room**

Answer (score -1):

I didn't want to submit more suggestions but just now I realized nobody mentioned this classic:

**The Travel Bug**

Answer (score -2):

Here's a couple of international destinations famous for being totally overrun by tourists:

- [**Freak Street**](http://www.hayhurst.net/adventure.html) (Street in Kathmandu, Nepal named after the hippies in the 60s that got there by the hippie trail)
- [**Khaosan Road**](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Khaosan_Road) (Current hub in Bangkok for years of tourists entering, leaving, or just stuck permanently in Southeast Asia)

Comment: Perhaps too local

Answer (score -3):

And what about:

**Customs & Immigration**

Answer (score -4):

And then there's **Stop Over** or **Lay Over**.

Answer (score -5):

How about **The Spanish Steps**?

(A large staircase in Rome permanently occupied by hoards of travelers hanging out)

Answer (score -5):

[The Last Homely House](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rivendell)